# PHP code to display db data

Tags: php, database

Hi guys I have a problem with my PHP, What I am trying to achieve is this:

```
<li><a href="main.html" class="title">Product name from DB</a>
        <strong>&pound;499<a href="main.html"><img src="images/thumb.png" alt="Product name from DB"/></a></strong>
  </li>
```

and here is my code with php:

```
<ul id="items">
    <?php while($product_data = mysql_fetch_array($query_product_result))
  {
    $num_rows_products = $num_rows_products - 1;
    Print "<li><a href = 'main.php?prodid=" . $product_data["product_id"] . " <strong> Name:  " . $product_data["title"] . "</strong></a>";
    Print "<strong>Price: &pound;" . $product_data["price"] .  "'><img src='images/" . $product_data["mainImageThumbnail"] . "' alt='Product image' /></a></strong></li>";
    if($num_rows_products > 0)
            Print '<p> nu products ? wtf</p>';
  }
  ?>
```

For some reason all I get is an image with a hyperlink, no title and no price, any chance you can spot the mistake?

Comment: is fetched object having data ??

Comment: Post the line with your SQL query.

Comment: check whether your query is executing or not

Comment: I'd say post the html markup as you delivered it to the client! You can use the browsers "View source" for this. Or its development console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not closing the `<a>` tag properly. See the code below. Notice the missing ">" in your code?

```
Print "<li><a href = 'main.php?prodid=" . $product_data["product_id"] . "'> <strong> Name:  " . $product_data["title"] . "</strong></a>";
    Print "<strong>Price: &pound;" . $product_data["price"] .  "<img src='images/" . $product_data["mainImageThumbnail"] . "' alt='Product image' /></a></strong></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Echo` instead. `Print` won't displays concatenated string.

```
 <ul id="items">
        <?php while($product_data = mysql_fetch_array($query_product_result))
      {
        $num_rows_products = $num_rows_products - 1;
        echo "<li><a href = 'main.php?prodid=" . $product_data["product_id"] . " <strong> Name:  " . $product_data["title"] . "</strong></a>";
        echo "<strong>Price: &pound;" . $product_data["price"] .  "'><img src='images/" . $product_data["mainImageThumbnail"] . "' alt='Product image' /></a></strong></li>";
        if($num_rows_products > 0)
                echo '<p> nu products ? wtf</p>';
      }
      ?>
```